# Java exceptions catch Beginner

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm learning try and catch exception with java and I have some problems. Indeed, I have setup ArithmeticException catch & try but the exception is not catch in some cases...

My Recursion.java :

```
import java.lang.ArithmeticException;

public class Recursion {

    private int u0;
    private int u1;

    public Recursion(int u0, int u1) {

        this.u0 = u0;
        this.u1 = u1;

    }

    public int boucle (int n) throws ArithmeticException{

        switch (n) {
        case 0 :
            return this.u0;
        case 1 :
            return this.u1;
        }


        try{

            if ( (n%2) == 0 ) {
                return (boucle(n-1) / boucle(n-2)) - (boucle(n-2) / boucle (n-1));
            }

            else{
                return (boucle(n-2) / boucle(n-1)) - (boucle(n-1) / boucle (n-2));
            }
        } 
        catch (ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("Erreur division par 0 !");
            throw e;
        }


    }

}
```

My Main.java :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Recursion monObjet1 = new Recursion (100,2);
        Recursion monObjet2 = new Recursion (100,1);

        System.out.println(monObjet2.boucle(10));


    }

}
```

I obtain this :

```
Erreur division par 0 !
Erreur division par 0 !
Erreur division par 0 !
Erreur division par 0 !
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Recursion.boucle(Recursion.java:32)
    at Recursion.boucle(Recursion.java:32)
    at Recursion.boucle(Recursion.java:32)
    at Recursion.boucle(Recursion.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

I dont understand why the exception is not catch...

Some of the output code may be in French I apologize for the inconvenience...

Best Regards,
Astrus

Comment: you catch the exception but then throw it again with `throw e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not catching it in your `main` method anymore (unlike the other methods where you catch and rethrow it). It will then be thrown out of the main method and be handled by the default exception handler for that thread, resulting in printing the full stacktrace of the exception.

Add a `try-catch` to your main method and **don't** rethrow the exception to avoid printing of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is catched as you can see in your console. But it is thrown again by `throw e;`. If you delete it no stack trace will be written to the console.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
throw e;
```

Throws your exception outside of boucle method into main. You need to catch this exception in your main method.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove try-catch from boucle method and put in main method.

```
import java.lang.ArithmeticException;

class Recursion {

    private int u0;
    private int u1;

    public Recursion(int u0, int u1) {

        this.u0 = u0;
        this.u1 = u1;

    }

    public int boucle(int n) throws ArithmeticException {

        switch (n) {
        case 0:
            return this.u0;
        case 1:
            return this.u1;
        }

        if ((n % 2) == 0) {
            System.out.println("if " + (n - 1));

            return (boucle(n - 1) / boucle(n - 2))
                    - (boucle(n - 2) / boucle(n - 1));
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("else" + (n - 1));
            return (boucle(n - 2) / boucle(n - 1))
                    - (boucle(n - 1) / boucle(n - 2));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Recursion monObjet1 = new Recursion(100, 2);
        Recursion monObjet2 = new Recursion(100, 1);
        try {
            System.out.println(monObjet2.boucle(10));
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {

            System.out.println("Erreur division par 0 !");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer ! I think I didn't really understand what "throw e" was doing... Can you explain me what this line is doing please ?